# Bracket line with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create a horizontal curly bracket using CSS or another technique? I don't know in advance how width the curly bracket will be, and I can have multiple curly brackets on the same page with different width (but the same height). My first idea was to use an image that I stretch to get the correct width, but I don't want the image to be distorted. So I looking for another solution.

The bracket will be used to add descriptions under an complicated table. See simple example below.

[image: Example image]

Comment: It's called a [curly brace](https://codepen.io/mexn/pen/xegaF) (first result on google)

Comment: Well, you could use a } character, just set the font-size high enough and `transform: rotate(90deg)` to rotate it on its side.

Comment: People need to learn that CSS is not a graphical drawing program.

Comment: To us the curly brace char is clever. But is it possible to have multiple braces on the same page with different width but same height?

Comment: @Rob I agree width you that you should not overuse CSS for graphical elements. I'm open for a suggestion how I can do this without CSS.

Comment: You should do this with an image or with svg.

Comment: An image was also my first idea, but the problem is that the brackets are of different width and I do not know in advance what width they will have. I can stretch the image to different widths, but the image would be distorted then.

Answer (score 3):

You could use two elements for each side and on each `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. Then you can use border-radius to create half circles and rotate them.

```css
.parent {
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  max-width: 300px;
}
.el {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.el>div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  margin: 20px 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.el>div:before,
.el>div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.el>div:after {
  right: -30px;
}
.right:after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  top: -30px;
}
.left:before {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
}
.left:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.right:before {
  left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="el">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non, sequi.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will give you what you need - you can adjust CSS styling to your own requirements.

**HTML**

```
 <span>}</span>
 <p>
    Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum, 
    Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum 
 </p>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 96px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.75);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.75);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.75);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.75);
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.75);
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 50px;
}
```

Link to JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7qLt8gcw/

Comment: Great solution. But is it possible to control the width of the curly brace?

Comment: You can update the transform properties to have a scale - see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. But how should I do if I want the bracket to be as width as a table cell? See https://jsfiddle.net/7qLt8gcw/1/